# Find first vowel in a column and display it in the next column

Tags: vba, excel, multiple-columns

what I am trying to do is very basic. I want to loop through the full column "I" and then display this vowel in column "M". But I want to loop through all the 1000+ rows in that column. Here is what I got so far, but I get an error referencing an object-based.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim mystring As String, i As Long, asciinum As String, f As Long

    For f = 1 To Rows.Count
        Rows(f, "I") = mystring
        For i = 1 To Len(mystring)
            asciinum = LCase(Mid(mystring, i, 1))
            If asciinum = "a" Or asciinum = "e" Or asciinum = "i" Or asciinum = "o" Or asciinum = "u" Then
                Rows(f, "M") = "First Vowel " + asciinum
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        Exit For
    Next
End Sub
```

Probably an error with the array and For...Loop?

Comment: Changed it, still getting the same error. "Application-defined or object-defined error". Marking that exact row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the value assignment backwards and need to use `Cells` instead of `Rows`.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim mystring As String, i As Long, asciinum As String, f As Long

    For f = 1 To Rows.Count
        mystring = Cells(f, "I").Value2
        For i = 1 To Len(mystring)
            asciinum = LCase(Mid(mystring, i, 1))
            If asciinum = "a" Or asciinum = "e" Or asciinum = "i" Or asciinum = "o" Or asciinum = "u" Then
                Cells(f, "M") = "First Vowel " + asciinum
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        Exit For
    Next
End Sub
```

This should work on the ActiveSheet but you should start getting into the practice of used a defined parent worksheet and only use the cells with values in them instead of looping all the way down to the bottom of the worksheet.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim mystring As String, i As Long, asciinum As String, f As Long

    With Worksheets("sheet1")
        For f = 1 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
            mystring = .Cells(f, "I").Value2
            For i = 1 To Len(mystring)
                asciinum = LCase(Mid(mystring, i, 1))
                If asciinum = "a" Or asciinum = "e" Or asciinum = "i" Or asciinum = "o" Or asciinum = "u" Then
                    .Cells(f, "M") = "First Vowel " + asciinum
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next i
        Next f
    End With
End Sub
```

I've also removed the second `Exit For` so that it continues the outer loop.

Comment: GREAT! This works. But It is not looping through the whole column. It just stays and stops at the first column (in this case "I1" and then stops). Any thoughts?Thanks for the quick and nice response.

Comment: You could simplify this  a lot by using `Like` : such as `If asciinum like "[aeiou]" Then`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a macro to find it, a formula will do - Assuming the `A1` is the cell you checking, `=MID(A1,FIND({"a","e","i","o","u"},A1),1)` will do it

Comment: That may very well be, but uhmmm, I am planning to do a lot of validation to each row, so I need to manage them all and Ive read it is easy to do it in VBA (since I am a Java/C# user). This is just the first one. If you have any idea, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks for the response tho :)

Comment: At least use instr rather than looping through all the letter

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I went for the all too powerful dark arts of RegEx:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    'Requires reference to "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expression 5.5"

    Dim mystring As String, i As Long, asciinum As String, f As Long
    Dim regFindVowels As New RegExp
    Dim FoundVowels As Variant
    regFindVowels.Pattern = "[AEIOUaeiou]"
    regFindVowels.Global = True

    With Worksheets("Sheet 1") ' change this to your sheetname
        For f = 1 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
            Set FoundVowels = regFindVowels.Execute(.Cells(f, "I").Value2)
            If FoundVowels.Count > 0 Then .Cells(f, "M") = "First Vowel " + FoundVowels(0) ' (0) is first, (1) is second etc.
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```